# "Retrieving docker inspect" requires at least 1 argument in bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to check container is up and running in the bash script. I am able to retrieve name of the dockder container but I am facing issue in docker inspect

```
CONTAINER=sudo docker ps -qf "name=pipeline"
echo $CONTAINER

RUNNING=$(docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} $CONTAINER 2> /dev/null)
STARTED=$(docker inspect -f {{.State.StartedAt}} $CONTAINER)
NETWORK=$(docker inspect -f {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}} $CONTAINER)
echo "OK - $CONTAINER is running. IP: $NETWORK, StartedAt: $STARTED"
```

Also tried with the below format

```
 docker inspect --format='{{.State.StartedAt}}' $CONTAINER) with sudo and without sudo
```

Running bash script command

```
 bash ./testing.sh
```

Error

```
"docker inspect" requires at least 1 argument.
 See 'docker inspect --help'.
 Usage:  docker inspect [OPTIONS] NAME|ID [NAME|ID...]
 Return low-level information on Docker objects
 Template parsing error: template: :1: unexpected unclosed action in range
 OK -  is running. IP: , StartedAt:
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the container's name, you can just use it in commands like `docker inspect`; you don't need the initial lookup.

```sh
RUNNING=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' pipeline 2> /dev/null)
```

*Always* quote shell variables that you expect to be used as parameters.  If the variable `$CONTAINER` comes back empty, but when you use it it's quoted, there will be a parameter there; if it's not quoted, it just gets dropped from the command.  (But you'll get a different error if you try to `docker inspect ""` with an empty container name.)

```sh
STARTED=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.StartedAt}}' "$CONTAINER")
```

The container-private IP address isn't useful in many environments (on MacOS or Windows hosts, if Docker is inside a VM, calling from a different host).  I would not recommend looking it up at all.

If you're just trying to get this diagnostic state from Docker, and not trying to act on it within the script, you can just write everything in the `-f` template option.  Combining this all together, I might replace everything in the script in the question with the single command

```sh
docker inspect \
  -f 'Container {{.Id}} is {{.State.Status}}, started at {{.State.StartedAt}}' \
  pipeline
```

Don't write `sudo` in scripts, but run the script with `sudo` permissions if you need that to run `docker` commands.

Comment: Thank you so much your answer is so helpful with so many tips you suggested for new comers like us its really helpful @DavidMaze